# PHP change 0.1 to 0.10

Tags: php

Is there a PHP function that will make the number always have 2 decimals places, even if it's 0?

Comment: Not a number, there are countless ways / functions to give you back a string, but a _single_ cast (mathmatical operation for instance) will revert it back to the previous float. PHP has no decimals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but you can format a number to a *string with decimals*

- [`number_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) — Format a number with grouped thousands

Example:

```
echo number_format(0, 2); // 0.00
```

---

**EDIT:** the `printf`/`sprintf` solutions suggested deserve some upvotes too

Comment: $iPrice =  number_format($aVars['Price'], 2);  didn't work it's still 0.1

Comment: @whatshakin do `echo number_format($aVars['Price'], 2);` And also take note that PHP will type juggle the returned string as it needs it for any subsequent operations. If it turns the formatted string back to a float, it will of course lose the second decimal.

Comment: number_format converts the float to a string for display. If you cast if back (explicitly or through math operators), it will drop the trailing 0. Best thing to do is use number_format no sooner than when you finally display the number to the user.

Comment: ok, that worked better.  Don't know what I was thinking trying to get it the database like that.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean you want to print additional digits even if there's only one digit after the decimal? You can do something like:

```
$x = 0.1;
printf("%.2f", $x);
```